# count max() values in a sparse matrix by row (dataframe)

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a sparse matrix with a few columns and I want to count by row when a value is equal to the max value of that row
How can this be done?
Let's say the data looks like this:

```
index    A    B    C    D    MAX
0        0    0    2    1    2
1        1    4    1    0    4
2        0    3    2    3    3
```

where the outcome should be:

```
index    A    B    C    D    MAX
  0      0    0    1    0    2
  1      0    1    0    0    3
  2      0    1    0    1    4
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
m=[[0, 0, 2, 1],[1, 4, 1, 0],[0, 3, 2, 3]]
df = pd.DataFrame(m)
maximums = df.max(axis=1)
maxmatrix = [[int(m[i][j] == maximums[i]) for j in range(df.shape[1])] for i in range(df.shape[0])]
print(maxmatrix)
```

returns

```
[[0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1]]
```